# List of source files - naming convention

Tags: makefile, backup, archive

I want to update few of my Makefiles. I want to add backup recipe. It will just create two zips, one for sources and second for binaries (+headers).

For that reson, I want to create file containing list of source files I want to add to archive. I am wondering about filename for that list.

Is there any standard for naming such a list? What is your convention?

Comment: I don't think that any such standard exists. You are free to choose a file name that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NAME = StackOverflow.exe
VERSION = 0.1.0
BASE_NAME = $(basename $(NAME))
.....
PKG = $(wildcard $(BIN)/*.dll) $(BIN)/$(NAME)
PKG_SRC = $(SRC) README.org makefile 

pkgdir:
    @mkdir -p pkg

pkg: $(PKG) | pkgdir
    tar -jcf pkg/$(BASE_NAME)-$(VERSION).tar.bz2 $^
    zip pkg/$(BASE_NAME)-$(VERSION).zip $^

pkgsrc: $(PKG_SRC) | pkgdir
    tar -jcf pkg/$(BASE_NAME)-$(VERSION)-src.tar.bz2 $^
    zip pkg/$(BASE_NAME)-$(VERSION)-src.zip $^
```

So, the binary backup file has name `StackOverflow-0.1.0.zip` and source backup file `StackOverflow-0.1.0-src.zip`